# Next JS: SSG Pageprops not change in production but work in dev

Tags: next.js

So i had Container Component that pass props to the meta

```js
export default function Container({ children, ...customMeta }) {
  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
  const { resolvedTheme, setTheme } = useTheme();

  // After mounting, we have access to the theme
  useEffect(() => setMounted(true), []);

  // const { children, ...customMeta } = props;
  const router = useRouter();
  const meta = {
    title: 'title',
    description: `description`,
    image: '',
    type: 'website',
    ...customMeta
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-900">
      <Head>
        <title>{meta.title}</title>
        <meta name="robots" content="follow, index" />
        <meta content={meta.description} name="description" />
      
.....
```

On development, the title showed up, but on production it didn't. It just showed the url.

I had tried to remove all fetch error but it still not work. Any help?